# How to pass extra variables at login to be added as extra claims?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am doing an implementation of ASP NET IDENTITY 3.1.12 in an ASP NET CORE 3.1.12 application and I would like to know if it is possible to pass extra variables into my custom class that implements the UserClaimsPrincipalFactory class so that they can be used as claims.

If it is not possible how I could obtain these extra variables within the AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory class or how I could add these variables to the claims of the logged in user.

Note: I don't want to save these variables in the database, just add them to the claims during login.

Thanks.

Thanks.

> UserRepository

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    #region Properties

    private readonly SignInManager<CustomIdentityUser> _signInManager;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public UserRepository(SignInManager<CustomIdentityUser> signInManager)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Authentication

    public void Logar(string myExtraStringVariableOrObject, string userName, string password)
    {
        //Here I would like to pass my extra variable to get it inside the CreateAsync method

        var signInResult =
            _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, false, false);

        if (signInResult.Result.Succeeded)
        {
            //OK
        }            
    }

    #endregion
}
```

> AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory

```
public class AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomIdentityUser, CustomIdentityRole>
{
    public AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(UserManager<CustomIdentityUser> userManager, RoleManager<CustomIdentityRole> roleManager,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
        : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
       
    }                

    public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(CustomIdentityUser customIdentityUser)        
    {
        var claimsPrincipal = await base.CreateAsync(customIdentityUser);
        var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)claimsPrincipal.Identity;

        //I would like to get my extra variable here

        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("myExtraStringVariableOrObject", "???????"));
        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Nome", customIdentityUser.Name));

        return claimsPrincipal;
    }       
}
```

> Startup ConfigureServices

```
//Identity Settings           
services.AddIdentityConfiguration();
```

> Identity Configuration

```
public static class IdentityConfiguration
{
    public static void AddIdentityConfiguration(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (services == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
        }

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<CustomIdentityUser>()
            .AddRoles<CustomIdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<LocacaoDbContext>();

        services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomIdentityUser>,
            AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();

    }
}
```

Comment: looks like you don't want to persist the additional claims? one way is to try sharing the info via the `HttpContext` (such as `HttpContext.Items`) and access the info via an `IHttpContextAccessor` (be sure to check null for `HttpContext`).

Comment: @KingKing Exactly, I don't want to save this data in the database. In fact, I already have this data saved in another database that would be a Connection String that I need to add to the claims. I believe that claims are a safe place to keep this information.
Can you tell me if it is safe to add a Connection String (sensitive data) to HttpContext.Items?

Comment: the `HttpContext.Items` is just an in-memory collection available in the current request's scope. So if the data is sensitive, any code that can access  `HttpContext.Items` can have a chance to do with that data. As long as you trust your code & the third-party code (e.g: with a middleware), I think it's fine (but of course not completely safe). It's like the scenario of modular app accepting a malicious module/plugin. If you want it to be safest, just encrypt it (and decrypt back when needed).